# Intuitive understanding of Tamagawa measure and its relationship between local measures?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, automorphic-forms, adeles

Weil's book Basic Number Theory, (1973, second edition) pp. 113 mentioned the Tamagawa measure on $k_\mathbb{A}$, where $k$ is a global field and $k_\mathbb{A}$ its ring of adeles (an old fashioned notation). So it's defined according to the following process:

First, we know that by definition the (additive) group of adeles is locally compact, Hausdorff. Then by the general theory of Haar measure, we can pick a unique $\alpha$ such that $\alpha(k_\mathbb{A}/k)=1$, which is defined to be the Tamagawa measure on the group of adeles. And by a computation carried out on pp. 112, we know that if we pick the self dual measures (with respect to Fourier transform) $\alpha_v$ on each place $v$ of $k$, then $\alpha=\prod \alpha_v$.

This is a nice result, and I know how to deal with it down to earth: you pick a "fundamental" open set on $k_\mathbb{A}$ of the form $U=\prod U_v$, where $U_v$ is an open set in $k_v$ and almost all $U_v=R_v$ (the ring of integers of $k_v$). Then the formula simply means $\alpha(U)=\prod \alpha_v(U_v)$ (the product is well-defined since all but finitely many are $1$).

OK. Now what makes me puzzled is the following: to be explicit and clearer, for example, $k=\mathbb{Q}$. You have prepared all $\alpha_p$ and $\alpha_\infty$ which are self-dual. Now I "adjust" $\alpha_2'=\lambda\cdot\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3'=1/\lambda\cdot\alpha_3$ for some $\lambda>0$, and keep other $\alpha_v’=\alpha_v$. Then by definition we must have $\alpha'=\prod \alpha_v'$ is also the Tamagawa measure, since its value on a standard open set $U=\prod\mathbb{Z}_p\times [0,1]$ is the same as the original one.

This looks somewhat weird for me (as a beginner). So you can "adjust" (arbitrarily many!) finitely many local measures without change the Tamagawa measure itself. Is this true? (I'm not quite sure as a new comer.) If this is the case, then how to understand this phenomenon intuitively? Of course usually we shall construct the Tamagawa measure following the above standard process. But in general by this observation, we can't use Tamagawa measure to point out any local measure on finitely many places? Thanks a lot in advance for your explanation!

Comment: Your question is fairly detailed so this might not be an issue, but generally speaking, never give page numbers unless you specifiy the exact edition of the book you are using.

Comment: @CaptainLama I see. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: I don't know Weil's treatment, but normally you define local Tamagawa measures and then take a product of them on the global space (or sometimes modify things by scalars at some finite number of places).  Does Weil start with a global measure and prove it is product of local Tamagawas?

Comment: @Kimball Oh, he also started from the local case. What made me puzzled is: you can freely change finitely many local measures without changing the adelic one. So in general we can’t recover any information of a finite set of  local measures from the given global one? I just found this somewhat subtle for adelic objects . Thank you!

Comment: Hint: just think about the case of product measures on 2 locally compact Hausdorff groups $G = H_1 \times H_2$.  What does your construction do the the measure of a product subset $U_1 \times U_2$.

Comment: @Kimball Ah, I see. The only subtle thing is: Adele is somewhat “infinite dimensional”

Answer (score 1):

One salient point is that, since you can only really change all the local measures simultaneously by a *global* number $\lambda$, the product formula $\prod_v |\lambda|_v=1$ says that the *global* measure does not change.